Please use the correct accents on Italian words
This is a plea for native Italians: could you please use the correct spelling of words with accents in your writing? 
I ask you this not only because it's nice to have things correctly spelled on a quality website, but also for the benefit of learners who might get confused if they see a word with a weird spelling.
I understand that on mobile devices inserting an accented letter is not that straightforward and one is easily tempted to replace the accent with the apostrophe, but I believe a little care in this would be highly appreciated by everyone.
Thank you!

It's an absolutely reasonable request, but sadly many Italians just don't know every word that needs the accent. Or the correct use of acute and grave accent.
For example, I rarely see the verb "dà" (third person, present tense of "dare") written with its accent.
The same with "perché", it's hard to see it with the correct accent, a lot of people write it as "perchè".  
I'm pretty sure that it's not due to laziness, just a lack of correct grammar.

I wasn't even referring to the distinction between accents. Using the accent instead of the apostrophe is a higher level inaccuracy. Anyway we should certainly make an effort to use correct accents as well.

I'm pretty sure that it is due to lazyness: I already have to press the shift key too many times when typing, doing so for every accented letter just slows me down too much, so I usually just put the default accent on the key. Fun fact: on mobile devices it's easier because they tend to autocorrect words, so the claim in question is false (at least in my experience). This say, I agree that we should try to use correct spelling and grammar, but I don't see it as a huge problem (besides learners has to learn that Italians don't use them correctly anyway on the Internet).

Writing with "K" and "X" instead of "ch" and "per" is laziness. Forgetting an accent or using it on the wrong word is just ignorance. Anyway what you wrote about about mobile devices is correct, but that's not always true because there are several words that can be written without accent and still have sense for the autocorrector, but not in the sentence.

it's pure laziness or ignorance (especially in the case of pò instead of po').
Except for "E'" and "È": it's a sad thing that Italy adopted a keyboard layout (different from any other layout) that does not allow you to write correct Italian! And yet, Swiss and German keyboards can write that character just fine.
Also on "perché" and "perchè": the pronunciation in northern Italy reflects the spelling "perchè", the Tuscan pronunciation (which is the canonical one) reflects how it's really written. Maybe this generates confusion.

«that does not allow you to write correct Italian!» Windows does not allow you to write correct Italian. Writing "È" in Linux is easy peasy.
